# jQuery image gallery with Ajax call back to load other images

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I want to build a simple image gallery with jQuery. I have a lot of photos to show on gallery page. So, I will not load all photos at once.
I will show only one photo first and then will load another photo from an Ajax callback when the user click "Next" link or button. 
If a photo is loaded, there's no need to do Ajax call back for that photo when the "Previous" link is click.

I really like the [Bing](http://www.bing.com) front page gallery, because it has the Ajax call back for the next photo and keeps loaded ones.

I already have a server side code that have many webservices that return JSON result of photo URL or portion of HTML that has imag tag.

I cannot find the right jQuery plug-in that help to building a simple gallery at the moment. 
 If you know one that can help me implement something like that, please recommend it. Thank you.

Comment: I voted to close since there are tons of almost similar questions and answers on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+image+gallery Some deeper look would give you the answer you need ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one here http://highslide.com/